# Can I change or add a property for my release number to the svn repository?

Tags: svn, svn-client, svn-propset

Svn is generating automatic numbers for revisions.

```
RevNo  Date         Desc
1      2012-01-01   Initial directories are created 
2      2012-01-02   Something added 
3      2012-03-10   something changed
4      2012-03-18   Ready for Release_1.0 and tags/Release_1.0 is ok
5      2012-03-19   Bug fixed
6      2012-03-18   Release_1.0.1
```

Can I change the revNo 4 to 1.0 ?
Can I add some property which can carry the Release Number like:

```
ReleaseNo RevNo  Date         Desc
0          1      2012-01-01   Initial directories are created 
0          2      2012-01-02   Something added 
0          3      2012-03-10   something changed
1.0        4      2012-03-18   Ready for Release_1.0 and tags/Release_1.0 is ok
0          5      2012-03-19   Bug fixed
1.0.1      6      2012-03-18   Release_1.0.1
```

And If I can add property how can I retrieve using by `svn.exe` ?
Like:
`c:\Projects\Test\trunk\>svn.exe info`with what kind params should I run?

Thanks in advance for your kind help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change revision numbers, but you can add revision properties with `svn propset <PROPNAME> --revprop -r <REV> <PROPVAL> [TARGET]`. You can also set a revision property during commit, e.g.:

```
svn commit -m "Commit message" --with-revprop "release-version=2.0.1"
```

To retrieve revision property use `svn propget <PROPNAME> --revprop -r <REV> [TARGET]`. See [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.html) for more information on properties.

*Note:* often by default setting of revision properties is disabled altogether or allowed only for `svn:log` property. You need to modify `pre-revprop-change` hook (or to contact your SVN administrator to do it for you).

You can also **tag** your code. See [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.tags.html). The advantage of tagging is that you can use code from different revisions in the same tag (say, one component can come from a different revision, including a different branch).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Tagging is that the thing I am always using. in my questing as you probably saw `tags/Release_1.0` is show my using style. I didn't want to split the url that's because I looked for another short thing which can helpfull for me. I wonder that can I create `ReleaseNo` as a new property? You said that `--revprop` . Is this generic name or reserved but not used property of svn? Can I add property like `BuildNumber` and can I force it has to be inserted in every commit?

Comment: `--revprop` is the name of the option. `<PROPNAME>` is the name of the property, e.g.: `svn propset ReleaseNo --revprop -r 123 "2.0.1" .`

Answer (score 1):

**References**:
 http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html
 http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.html
 http://johnbokma.com/mexit/2008/09/30/subversion-svn-keywords-property.html
 http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re23.html

I used tortoise to make it happen.

[image: SVN Property will be setted]

Property name: ReleaseNo
Default value: 0.0 
In this folder every new file/folder will have ReleaseNo attribute with the 0.0 default value.
I will be able to set the RleaseNo property when I create every tag.
Propset and propget will work to setting and getting the ReleaseNo.
I wanted to add new textbox into branch/tag form of Tortoise to enter the right ReleaseNo quickly but it'll take a lot time.
[image: Under the tags folder ReleaseNo property has been created]

[image: Folders are setted with set Release Number]

[image: With a commit changings are submitting to the repository]

[image: And the result]